# Load HTML file into a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to make a modal with dynamically loaded content. This is my JavaScript code:

```
function track(id,title) {
    $('#listenTrack').modal('show');
    $('#listenTrack').find('.modal-title').html(title);
    $.get("remote.html", function(data) {

        $('#listenTrack').find('.modal-body').html(data);

    });
}
```

And here is remote.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">var zippywww="26";var zippyfile="9k9lOOtw";var zippytext="#C9302C";var zippyback="#161617";var zippyplay="#ff6600";var zippywidth=320;var zippyauto=false;var zippyvol=80;var zippywave = "#C9302C";var zippyborder = "#cccccc";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.zippyshare.com/api/embed_new.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried also without html tags, but nothing. The **text content appears, not the player**. And if I open `remote.html` directly from the browser everything is fine.
Maybe my code is wrong.

Comment: everythings is right in this code! more information required !
do you check developer console ? do you try to print data variable with console.log(data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i see in your solution i can notice that you are not loading your **boostrap.js** file,unless this block of code is not your snippet in its totality.

Here is a simple solution that  worked for me :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>



<div class="modal fade" id="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>




<script>
(function(){
    // 1 :the content that we want to inject inside our modal 
    //  this content can be loaded from another external file, this is just an example 
    var content = {title:"this is the title ",body:"this is the body content"};

    // reference my modal 
    var modal1=$('#modal1');
    // use `.html(content)` or `.text(content)` if you want to the html content 
    // or text content respectively.
    $(modal1).find('.modal-title').html(content.title);
    $(modal1).find('.modal-body').html(content.body);

    // show the modal 
    $(modal1).modal();


})();   

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

the modal used in this example is from the bootstrap official website  : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Don't forget to load **jquery first**, because bootstrap depends on it.
Secondly load your `bootstrap.js` without forgetting `bootstrap.css` in the **head section**.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a highly cross-browser compatible solution. It uses the XMLHttpRequest Object's open method to open your "remote.html" file using HTTP GET method. The third parameter ***true*** is to mark that the request as asynchronous.

When loaded without errors (with an HTTP OK response), fill the **listenTrack** div with the HTML content of "remote.html".

```
var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'remote.html', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange= function() {
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    if (this.status!==200) return;
    document.getElementById('listenTrack').innerHTML= this.responseText;
};
xhr.send();
```

I repeat, this is highly cross-compatible (except few older versions of IE, which is now - no more) and doesn't even require jQuery or any other javascript library.

Comment: should give an explanation why your code would work vs OP code as well as what your code does and where it would be used. `Try this` is not a proper explanation

Comment: @charlietfl: Apologies. i've added explanation to the answer now. Feel free to comment in case further explation or any thing else is needed. Thank you for pointing it out.